# Search-like jump to multiple anchors with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage with multiple anchors with the same name:

```
<a name=A>Andrew</a>
<a name=J>James</a>
<a name=B>Bill</a>
<a name=J>Jane</a>
<a name=A>Ann</a>
<a name=J>Jack</a>
```

I want to have links

```
Click to find next: [A] [B] [J]
```

that behave much like search: cycle through all occurrences of the name.

That is, when you click `[J]` you get to `James`; when you click it again, you get to `Jane`; when you click it again, you get to `Jack`, and when you click it again, you get back to `James`, etc.

No problem if the user changes the caret position -- it's OK just to go to the next anchor after the current caret (exactly as search would do).

JavaScript or JQuery are OK, though if there is a simpler solution, better.

Comment: I would suggest to change the `name` attribute to `class`, could save you a few cross browser problems. What I'd like to know though is: what have you tried so far and what is the problem you are having?

Comment: I tried `<a href=J>[J]</a>`, but it always jumps to the first anchor. 

The task is a bit complicated to describe, but here is another example: jump to the next chapter title in the book (as one page). As you suggest, I can have them `<h1 class='chapter'>Adventures</h1>`, and I want a link or button in the sidebar of the page to jump to the next chapter title.

Comment: HTML alone does not offer you such a solution as you have discovered, you will need to use Javascript.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the HTML for this? Normally in this situation the links could be simple bookmark links in the content e.g. `<a href="#somitem">`.